# Bizarre timeout in Web CMS, ideas?

Tags: php, javascript, html

**I know this kind of thing cannot be adequately answered without a link to the live example.** Unfortunately, I can't set one up right now as it's a back-end login and creating a safe public login would be too much to do at this point. Sorry. I'm hoping for ideas and input from people who may have experienced something similar in the past.

I am setting up a CMS for a client with a DSL connection in Spain.

The CMS is hosted on a straightforward standard, LAMP based, shared hosting package in a network center in Germany.
It comes with a .com domain.

When my client tries to log in to the CMS using Internet Explorer 7, everything works fine.
When she tries to log in using Firefox, she gets to the login form, submits it - and then the connection times out.
When she logs in using Firefox but using "**domain.com**" instead of "**www.domain.com**", everything works fine.

This happens **on all computers** that are hooked up to that line. One Windows XP, one Windows Vista.

The front-end part of the site, as well as a second, older CMS, **work fine** in all browsers.

I do not have access to the raw access logs.

I have not been able to reproduce this behaviour on any other connection.

Debugging ideas are welcome. Remote diagnosis is extremely difficult as the line is too slow to set up a proper remote connection.

Comment: Could all the nodes connected through that line goes through some sort of proxy that strips cookie/session related HTTP header data?

Comment: Very unlikely. It's a mainstream, end-user DSL line provided by Telefonica. The line is a bit shaky altogether, but I can't imagine something this specific coming from it, especially as an older version of the same CMS on the same domain is running fine.

Comment: Make sure that the login form really posts to the desired domain and not example.com or something like that. Is there any JS trickery on the login page that might explain the different behaviors of different browsers?

Comment: I just managed to log on remotely and removed Firefox's cookies for that domain, and it works! It seems there are two session cookies, one for the old, one for the new CMS. I don't understand why there is a conflict - they run on different databases and other clients can deal with both CMSs without problems - but there obviously is one and I know where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are limited by how you can troubleshoot this, have the client install `Fiddler - Web debugging proxy` and then run the trace, and send you the logs, `Fiddler` will analyze the traffic (be it proxy or DNS timeout, etc)

Take a look if you have not used it before:

http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp

Comment: I didn't use fiddler, but am accepting this as I feel it's the closest answer. I just managed to log on remotely and removed Firefox's cookies for that domain, and behold, it works! It seems there are two session cookies, one for the old, one for the new CMS. I don't understand why there is a conflict - they run on different databases - but there obviously is one and I know where to look.

Comment: :-( I actually wrote an answer saying "Clear the browser cookies in Firefox", but then I deleted it when I re-read your description and saw it happened on many computers; I thought it unlikely to be a cookie problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check that Firefox and IE are using the same proxy settings.

Comment: Already checked, no proxy settings on either browser. It's a direct like through a router.

Answer (score 0):

DNS issues? can you put here your A records to check is everything is ok?